# SQL - Alphanumeric Sorting

Tags: sql

I have a table of Department in SQL that I am trying to sort alphanumerically. This is the following syntax I have come up with:

`SELECT DeptAbbreviation FROM [JBSIS_Odyssey].[VW_Probate_Courthouse_Department] ORDER BY LEFT(DeptAbbreviation,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',DeptAbbreviation)-1), CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(DeptAbbreviation,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',DeptAbbreviation),LEN(DeptAbbreviation)))`

It gives me an error message that says:
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I suspect it is because I have one value that reads:
ST2D, a number in between the characters.

Is there any solution to my existing code, thanks

Comment: i am confused... `ORDER BY DeptAbbreviation` should already give you an alphanumeric sort. maybe you defined the wrong `COLLATION` for your column?

Comment: Please explain what "sort alphanumerically" means.  It is not clear what you mean by this.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.